# Trouble Converting Pandas DataFrame Column dtypes to String of Certain Size (|S2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change a DataFrame's column dtype to S2. If I do it with float data, it works great:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[1.1,3.2,5.6]})
>>>df['b'] = df['b'].astype('|S4',copy=False)
>>>print(df.dtypes,'\n\n',df.memory_usage())
```

Returns:

```
a    int64
b      |S4
dtype: object 

 Index    80
a        24
b        12
dtype: int64
```

However, when I try the same with strings:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']})
>>>df['b'] = df['b'].astype('|S4',copy=False)
>>>print(df.dtypes,'\n\n',df.memory_usage())
```

Returns:

```
a     int64
b    object
dtype: object 

 Index    80
a        24
b        24
dtype: int64
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't replicate your output.  The dtypes and memory usage are the same for me in both cases.

Comment: Hi Bill, what version are you running? I'm wondering if this is a bug, and from your comment it sounds like it might be isolated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry @Devin I was reading my code output wrong.  I do get the same output as you.  Apologies for that.  I will delete my comment once you have responded.

Comment: Have you considered using this `df.memory_usage(deep=True)`.  "Memory usage does not include memory consumed by elements that are not components of the array if deep=False." Not exactly sure what this means but when I tried this I get numbers like 126 for column b.

Comment: @Bill
Sounds like this is a known issue:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9216
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14400

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bug. I think pandas tend to preserve the `object dtype` of existing column when the casting is done to dtypes other than int and float. So to change the `dtype` assign it to new column. i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['1.1','3.2','5.6']})

df['b'] = df['b'].astype('|S4',copy=False)
df['c'] = df['b'].astype('|S4',copy=False)
```

Output:

```
a     int64
b    object
c       |S4
dtype: object 

 Index    80
a        24
b        24
c        12
dtype: int64
```

Or a temporary solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['1.1','3.2','5.6']})
b = df['b'].astype('|S4',copy=False)
del df['b']
df['b'] = b

df.dtypes
```

```
a    int64
b      |S4
dtype: object
```

Comment: I had tried this and it works nicely... however the reason I'm doing this at all is to _reduce_ the memory allocation of a large DataFrame; it would be ideal to not have to duplicate the entire thing. This works in a pinch though. Thanks.

Comment: Well another think we can do is that store the df['b'] in a temporary variable then delete the existing column and add the new values.

Comment: It sounds like this is a known issue:
github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9216 
github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14400